# how do i check if something is written infront of some char

Tags: c#

I have a program which "translates" the dns to a IP-adress and I want to check
if something is infront of a '.' for  examlpe the user gives:
**Google.com**
Then I want to check if something is written infront of the '.' so the user can't make any program errors.

I have already a methode to check if there is a '.' in the text

```
if(Input.Text.Contains('.'))
{
    //Codeblock
}
```

Comment: You could just use `Uri.IsWellFormedUriString`?

Comment: Or `Input.Text.StartsWith(".")`. But yeah, what @trix said is the better solution (you should post that as an answer)

Comment: You mean like "google" is in front of the `.`?

Comment: yes but it could be anything else like facebook, youtube or else

Comment: you also could use a RegEx for IP Adresses

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The [Uri class](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.uri(v=vs.110).aspx) could really help you out with this as it's pretty useful for URL validation.

The [`IsWellFormedUriString`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.uri.iswellformeduristring(v=vs.110).aspx) method

> Indicates whether the string is well-formed by attempting to construct a URI with the string and ensures that the string does not require further escaping.

It returns true if the string was well-formed; else false.

```
bool valid = Uri.IsWellFormedUriString(url, UriKind.RelativeOrAbsolute);
```

Answer (score 2):

You can use `.IndexOf('.')` to get the index of the the `.` If it is 0 then you can be sure there is nothing in front of the `.`
[Docs](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.string.indexof(v=vs.110).aspx)

Comment: This answer seems odd, because with OP's sample text `Google.com` your "solution" wont result in `0`, since the `.` just isnt the first character `Google` is "infront" of the `.`

Comment: @RandRandom that's what the answer is saying: "If it is 0 **then** you can be sure there is **nothing** in front of the `.`"

Answer (score 0):

You can use [`String.IndexOf()`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.string.indexof?view=netframework-4.7.1#System_String_IndexOf_System_String_):

```
// find the dot
var dotLocation = Input.Text.IndexOf(".", StringComparison.Ordinal);

// if the dot exists in the text..
if (dotLocation > 0)
{
    // ..return the text before the dot
    // in your "Google.com" example this would return "Google"
    return Input.Text.Substring(0, dotLocation);
}
else
{
    // no text before the dot.
}
```